# How to get the texts of all items from QListWidget in Qt?

Tags: qt

How can I get the texts of all the widgets in a `QListWidget` as a `QList<QString>`?

I can get the list of widget items  like this:

```
QList<QListWidgetItem *> items =
      ui->listWidget->findItems(QString("*"), Qt::MatchWrap | Qt::MatchWildcard);
```

But that's not exactly what I want, I'd like the list of the widget `text()` properties.

Comment: you want a `QList<QString>` representing all the listWidget's item `text` properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in function for that, you'll need to do it manually.

```
QList<QString> texts;
foreach(QListWidgetItem *item, items)
  texts.append(item->text());
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
int c = ui->listWidget->count();
for (int i = 0; i < c ; ++i){

QString s = QString::number(i); 
QModelIndex *model_index = new QModelIndex(ui->listWidget->model()->index(i,0) ); //0th column since we have one cloumn in listwidget
QString q= model_index->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
qDebug()<<q;

}
```